# Long term luggage storage

Tags: luggage, belgium, brussels

I'm looking for a place in Brussels where I can leave my luggage (It's 28 inch suit case) for about 10 days. I found Brussels Midi train station offers storage but not sure if it offers it for such a long time.

Is it possible to store it long term at Midi train station or are there other alternatives?

Comment: According to [here](http://www.belgianrail.be/en/stations-and-train/search-a-station/1/bruxelles-midi.aspx) there are both *'staffed left-luggage service'* and *'automatic luggage lockers'* at Bruxelles-Midi. The [Man in Seat 61](http://www.seat61.com/luggage-lockers-at-stations.htm#Left_luggage_in_Brussels) says the same: *Brussels Midi has both luggage lockers and a staffed left luggage facility near the Eurostar check-in and Thalys reception.  Both are open 24 hours a day, the staffed facility costs €4.00 per item per calendar day, the 3 sizes of lockers cost €3, €3.50, €4 per 24 hours.*

Comment: @MH.: But none of this addresses whether you can use those lockers for 10 days.

Comment: @NateEldredge: *"the staffed facility costs €4.00 per item per calendar day"* - seems to imply this is meant for longer-term storage. You could give the operator of the staffed facility a call for a definitive answer. The closest I got is [this brochure](http://users.b-rail.be/bene_bs/images/thalys_services_nl.pdf), which mentions a max storage period of 72h for the automatic lockers, but none for the staffed ones (which presumably means extended periods are fine - I'd expect 10 days not to be a problem). Unfortunately, the brochure is from 2006... not sure if it's still in print.

Comment: @MH. Please edit the answer you pointed out with your details. Or add another answer altogether.

Comment: @JoErNanO: I updated the linked answer, to keep the information in one place (and because this thread was closed as dupe in the meantime).

Comment: @MH. [Come to the chat.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) :)

Comment: This is probably the right duplicate: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44130/place-to-leave-luggage-in-brussels-for-multiple-days