# Are the luggage storage lockers at Brussels-Midi still available for use in April 2016 after recent security clampdowns?

Tags: event-based-effects, brussels, luggage-storage, train-stations

We will be travelling catching flight in the evening from Brussels Airport but we are planning to arrive from Paris in the morning. I read that Bruxelles-Midi still have the locker for use on their website, however [seat61.com mentioned that some lockers may be closed](http://www.seat61.com/luggage-lockers-at-stations.htm#Left_luggage_in_Brussels):

> Bear in mind that the security situation in Belgium may affect the availability of left luggage lockers at the moment.  Some may be closed.

Does anyone know if this accurate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any places to leave luggage in Brussels, for short and/or long periods of time?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44130/are-there-any-places-to-leave-luggage-in-brussels-for-short-and-or-long-periods)

Comment: @JonathanReez the mention of Burxelles-Midi in the answer to that question is a general quote from Seat61 in March 2015. This question is asking about to what extent a specific point on Seat61 still applies in April 2016. It's *clearly* not answered by an out of date quote from the very website the asker referred to in their question.

Comment: @JonathanReez Maybe you don't read the news? In case you don't, I've updated the question to make it ***explicitly*** obvious why this is *not* a duplicate of a general question from before the terrorist attacks in Brussels...

Comment: @user568458 you can answer the question in the linked question, specifically focusing on the security issues

Comment: @JonathanReez Why? That's not what that question from over a year ago is about.

Comment: I'm heading through Brussels Midi tomorrow afternoon, I'll try to remember to check if no-one has beaten me to it!

Comment: The earlier question's answers should be updated if they're now wrong though.

Comment: Thanks @Gagravarr.. That would be great if you could inform me. My Question relates to the recent incident... I think my question is completely different from just asking whether there are luggage storage in Brussels-Midi...

Comment: @Gagravarr sorry, you can still double check ;)

Answer (score 18):

Yes, both automatic lockers and manned storage of left luggage are available as of today.

I just went to check myself. Everything is accessible and there is no sign whatsoever indicating anything particular. At the automatic lockers some were occupied (red light and locked), others were available (green light and I could open them). The manned storage was, well... manned. I didn't try to pay for obvious reasons.