# Key storage for later pickup at Brussels Airport

Tags: luggage-storage, brussels, bru

I'm looking for somewhere in Brussels airport to leave a set of keys for a friend to pick up. Is that possible?  I can't use lockers with a key or printed barcode as my friend won't have access to them. I would need to leave them at a manned desk. Many thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any places to leave luggage in Brussels, for short and/or long periods of time?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44130/are-there-any-places-to-leave-luggage-in-brussels-for-short-and-or-long-periods)

Comment: Understanding it correctly, you can't use lockers which open with a key or a printed barcode. Right?

Comment: @Arthur'sPass I'm voting against closing this as a duplicate, because OP needs *somebody else* to be able to retrieve the keys (presumably meaning, as Joren says, that they can't use a locker relying on physical keys or printed receipts to open). The other question doesn't have that requirement and its answers don't contain the relevant information.

Comment: Can your friend receive email? You could email a barcode or QR for his use.

Comment: Can you take a picture of the barcode and text it to your friend?